# What is the origin of Tal's expression "They can only take one at a time"?

Tags: history, tal, quotations

The expression refers to aggressive attacking style where one side leaves multiple pieces attacked, but the opponent cannot take full advantage of it since "they can only take one at a time". Was this said by Tal in an interview or in a book (assuming he was actually the one who said it)? Did he say it originally in Russian? If so - what is the exact Russian expression he used?

Comment: I played a tournament game last week, two days after you asked this, in which I [had 3 minor pieces en prise at once](https://edwardtdean.org/2018/09/30/they-can-only-take-them-one-at-a-time-mikhail-tal/) and I thought about your question during the game. Now I'm even more curious where Tal first said this. I'm tempted to offer a bounty for an answer, but I think that might go to waste right now.

Comment: @ETD I was curious about your game but the link appears to be broken.

Comment: @DanielAlfredoSottile edited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have seen this referred to/attributed to a couple of Tal's games. It is quite likely that he used the saying more than once. If you study enough of Tal's games, you'll see that he developed a technique of *not* retracting his (minor) pieces when they were en prise.

The first reference that I was able to find was in his **Havana-1966** game against Bjorn Brinck-Claussen. (Quite likely this position, where he's just moved Ra8!

```
[Title "Tal v Brinck-Claussen, Havana 1966 "]
[fen "R2r2k1/6pp/1p3pn1/3b2q1/3P4/P4QP1/BP3P2/6K1 w - - 0 1"]
```

The saying is also often  attributed to his **1968 game against Chikovani**, where Tal plays 19 Bxe6 instead of retracting his dark-squared Bishop.

```
[Title "Tal v Chikovani, 1968"]
[fen "1qrr2k1/p3bp2/bpn1Bnpp/6B1/3P4/P1N2N2/1PQ2PPP/3RR1K1 w - - 0 1"]
```

As you can see, in both cases Tal leaves multiple pieces hanging, a psychological strategy that he's used to his advantage.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Incidentally, Tal's move in the second example is incorrect. It gives Tal a big advantage but Black can defend for a long time. The correct move leads to checkmate quickly.